# Javascript Regex: matcing multiple groups in a line

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I use these user-agent lines. Mobile and Tablet user-agents found on this Chrome documentation site: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Chrome Mobile on Android:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 10 Build/JSS15Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2307.2 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Chrome Tablet on Android (Tablet string simply ignores the "Mobile" word, this is the difference):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; Nexus 10 Build/JSS15Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2307.2 Safari/537.36
```

My Chrome user-agent on Windows Desktop:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
```

I use these regexes:

```
window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)|(Chrome\/[.0-9]* Mobile)/ig)
window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)|(Chrome\/[.0-9]* (?!Mobile))/ig)
```

My problem is also matching the Chrome Desktop. I only want to target Chrome Mobile and Tablet, but not the Desktop. Seems like the Android word also ignored.

UPDATE:

```
/(?=Android).*(Chrome\/[.0-9]* (?=Mobile))/ig
/(?=Android).*(Chrome\/[.0-9]* (?!Mobile))/ig
```

Not perfect solution, because selecting everything til the end from `.*`

UPDATE - Solution: https://regex101.com/r/eT0zW5/1

Comment: You add classes (and perhaps styles?) whenever the devices is a tablet or mobile. Don't you just need media queries to target specific screen sizes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Can you explain with and example a successful match and an unsuccesful match?

Comment: Matching only Mobile and Tablet [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/rE5nQ0/1)

Comment: timing! What's happening on an UltraHD mobile screen, if I use media queries? A 15,6" 1366x768 laptop's screen is lower res. than some newest smart phone.

Comment: you shouldn't be detecting user agent, detect features instead, use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com). User agent is meaningless when you are coding for the actual features the browser possesses.

Comment: @user1442219 that doesn't matter. Those UltraHD devices still render everything at a lower resolution, but just with more detail (correct me if I'm wrong). And also, what IF a mobile device has a high resolution? You don't want to limit their experience right? Just optimize for resolution.

Comment: Thank You! Is there any article about this topic a mobile or tablet at what resolution rendering the webpage?

Comment: gwillie! Than how to target mobile and tablet with modernizr? Using modernizr's touch event also not a solution. Latest Win10 notebooks also touch devices.

Comment: Anyway, still waiting for the solution of the regex problem. Good to know for later use.